# classnotfound exception securityassociation wildfly v10

Tags: java, wildfly, classnotfound

Getting a classNotFound exception on Wildfly 10.0.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.security.SecurityAssociation from [Module "deployment.employee-app-1.2.1.ear.authorization-service-login-modules-jboss-1.1.2.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        ... 36 more
```

I tried adding the jbosssx jar to my ear but still getting the classNotFound issue.   Is it possible to add jar to a dir within Wildfly?

thanks

Comment: Are you using any type of building tool, like Gradle or Maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact point in time it happened but `org.jboss.security.SecurityAssociation` was renamed `org.jboss.security.SecurityContextAssociation`. Therefore by changing your references to `org.jboss.security.SecurityAssociation` in authorization-service-login-modules-jboss, you should be good to go.